# Error Code: 2068. LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access. i am using mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
Load  data LOCAL infile "C:\\ProgramData/MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\covidvaccination.csv" into table  `covid vaccination`
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by'\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

> ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.